# Split a string with a Carriage Return in the middle (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, talend

I have a problem and I don't know if I can resolve it.

I have a field (from a table) that have a Carriage Return in his middle (it is a field called AddressComplete and it has the street and the city), I want to take the street when the city contains "London".

Does anybody know how can I split this field?
The row separator is "\n" and the field separator is "\t"
(I'm using Talend, with Java language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you want:

```
String[] tokens = field.split("\r");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
for (String[] line : field.split("\n")) {
    String[] info = line.split("\t");
    String street = info[0];
    String city = info[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can provide newline regex or rely on the system property to get the system dependent newline character.
- split function splits the string into tokens

```
  String.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: What if the system newline character isn't the same as the one used in the file?